# Wi-Fi driver problem

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I installed Ubuntu yesterday (March 22, 2024) on an HP G62 laptop. Now I can't access the internet because I can't access Wi-Fi. The laptop's internal Wi-Fi is broken and I am using a local market Wi-Fi adapter. I tried to install different drivers and look up different solutions, but none of them is working because my device is different from what commonly people use.

My device ID (the top one device 013):

[image]

I don't have any wired connection to the laptop and I can't have any wired connection to the laptop, so the laptop is without internet now, but there is Windows 10 on that laptop too and I can dual boot to Windows and the Wi-Fi adapter works there.

Comment: try ``iwconfig'' command to see if interface name

Answer (score 0):

Googling "350b:9101 linux" gives no good results.  Similarly searching for "ZTop" finds windows drivers but not linux drivers.

Very likely this device is (currently?) unsupported in linux.

Your options are:

- wait for a driver to be written
- write a driver for the device
- pay someone else to write a driver
- get a different device that is supported by linux
- run linux in a vm inside windows instead